# Node.js stopped without any error log after sometime when idle

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on node.js project. My app is running fine when there is continuous load in the server. but when we keep it idle for few hours , it automatically stopped without giving error or exception.

We are using cluster npm and we are using 2 child process running in the master processes.

Comment: Please, add some helpful information to this question. A NodeJS application — it is anything.

Comment: How did you monitor its run? Have you considered the possibilities that a cat walked across the keyboard? Or that it lost internet access for a few seconds and your flawless error handling code didn't let it throw an error?

Comment: Are you using connections to database or cache? If those connections aren't keepAlive they might end up dying at some point.

Comment: @maxkoryukov it has nothing complex and nothing to add , it is very simple node application

Comment: @manelgarcia  yes we are using redis. and I have captured error logs and logs on connection close , but i didn't got anything. And the behaviour is abrupt some time it remain alive for 2 days but often get stopped in few hours